# how does exp_continue work? Issues with exp_continue

Tags: regex, tcl, expect

I'm trying to capture the inventory data off my cisco equipment. I though it would be pretty easy but I'm having issues.

instead of matching and entire "set" of data (from Name.+SN is one set) I thought I'd split my maches up and use `exp_continue` to make my Regex more readable.

If you look below, it seems exp_continue is being super greedy when it gathers the "name"

data set:

```
HOSTNAME#sho inventory
NAME: "WS-C6506-E", DESCR: "Cisco Systems, Inc. Catalyst 6500 6-slot Chassis System"
PID: WS-C6506-E        ,                     VID: V03, SN: SAL1547VW8B

NAME: "WS-C6K-VTT-E 1", DESCR: "VTT-E FRU 1"
PID: WS-C6K-VTT-E      ,                     VID:    , SN: SMT1541B899

NAME: "WS-C6K-VTT-E 2", DESCR: "VTT-E FRU 2"
PID: WS-C6K-VTT-E      ,                     VID:    , SN: SMT1541B910

NAME: "WS-C6K-VTT-E 3", DESCR: "VTT-E FRU 3"
PID: WS-C6K-VTT-E      ,                     VID:    , SN: SMT1541B903

NAME: "CLK-7600 1", DESCR: "OSR-7600 Clock FRU 1"
PID: CLK-7600          ,                     VID:    , SN: SMT1544A575

NAME: "CLK-7600 2", DESCR: "OSR-7600 Clock FRU 2"
PID: CLK-7600          ,                     VID:    , SN: SMT1544A575

NAME: "3", DESCR: "WS-X6724-SFP CEF720 24 port 1000mb SFP Rev. 5.1"
PID: WS-X6724-SFP      ,                     VID: V08, SN: SAL160214AY

NAME: "WS-F6700-CFC Centralized Forwarding Card sub-module of 3", DESCR: "WS-F6700-CFC Centralized Forwarding Card Rev. 4.1"
PID: WS-F6700-CFC      ,                     VID: V06, SN: SAL160317SU

NAME: "4", DESCR: "WS-X6324-100FX-MM 24 port 100FX Multi mode Rev. 3.6"
PID: WS-X6324-100FX-MM ,                     VID:    , SN: SAL091805J9

NAME: "5", DESCR: "WS-SUP720-3B 2 ports Supervisor Engine 720 Rev. 5.6"
PID: WS-SUP720-3B      ,                     VID: V05, SN: SAL1226UYLK

NAME: "msfc sub-module of 5", DESCR: "WS-SUP720 MSFC3 Daughterboard Rev. 3.1"
PID: WS-SUP720         ,                     VID:    , SN: SAL1226UXVD

NAME: "WS-F6K-PFC3B Policy Feature Card 3 sub-module of 5", DESCR: "WS-F6K-PFC3B Policy Feature Card 3 Rev. 2.3"
PID: WS-F6K-PFC3B      ,                     VID: V01, SN: SAL1225UQAQ

NAME: "6", DESCR: "WS-X6324-100FX-MM 24 port 100FX Multi mode Rev. 3.6"
PID: WS-X6324-100FX-MM ,                     VID:    , SN: SAL091805HU

NAME: "WS-C6506-E-FAN 1", DESCR: "Enhanced 6-slot Fan Tray 1"
PID: WS-C6506-E-FAN    ,                     VID: V03, SN: DCH1547004V

NAME: "PS 1 WS-CAC-3000W", DESCR: "AC power supply, 3000 watt 1"
PID: WS-CAC-3000W      ,                     VID: V02, SN: SNI1543AX19

NAME: "PS 2 WS-CAC-3000W", DESCR: "AC power supply, 3000 watt 2"
PID: WS-CAC-3000W      ,                     VID: V02, SN: SNI1543AX1F
HOSTNAME#
```

code:

```
send "show inventory\r"
expect {
        -nocase -re {NAME: "([^\"]+)"} {
                set NAME $expect_out(1,string)
                puts "Name $NAME!!!!"
                exp_continue
        }
        -nocase -re {DESCR: "([^\"]+)"} {
                set DESCR $expect_out(1,string)
                puts "Des $DESCR!!!!"
                exp_continue
        }
        -nocase -re {PID:([^,]+)} {
                set PID $expect_out(1,string)
                puts "PID $PID!!!!"
                exp_continue
        }
        -nocase -re {VID:([^,]+)} {
                set VID $expect_out(1,string)
                puts "VID $VID!!!!"
                exp_continue
        }
        -nocase -re {SN: ([^\r]+)} {
                set SN $expect_out(1,string)
                puts "SN $SN!!!!\n\n"
                lappend info "$hostname,$NAME,$DESCR,$PID,$VID,$SN"
                exp_continue
        }
        "#"
}
 foreach I $info {
   puts "$I"
  }
```

And here is the output

```
Name WS-C6506-E!!!!
Name WS-C6K-VTT-E 1!!!!
Name WS-C6K-VTT-E 2!!!!
Name WS-C6K-VTT-E 3!!!!
Name CLK-7600 1!!!!
Name CLK-7600 2!!!!
Name 3!!!!
Name WS-F6700-CFC Centralized Forwarding Card sub-module of 3!!!!
Name 4!!!!
Name 5!!!!
Name msfc sub-module of 5!!!!
Name WS-F6K-PFC3B Policy Feature Card 3 sub-module of 5!!!!
Name 6!!!!
Name WS-C6506-E-FAN 1!!!!
Name PS 1 WS-CAC-3000W!!!!
Name PS 2 WS-CAC-3000W!!!!
Des AC power supply, 3000 watt 2!!!!
PID  WS-CAC-3000W      !!!!
VID  V02!!!!
SN SNI1543AX1F!!!!

HOSTNAME,AC power supply, 3000 watt 2, WS-CAC-3000W      , V02,SNI1543AX1F
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the `NAME` match is always checked at first, you tend to see this behavior due to `exp_continue` which is misused here.

Instead of this, you can wait till the prompt of the your device. The whole output will be available in the `expect_out(buffer)`. Then apply the `regexp` to extract the required data.

```
send "show inventory\r"
expect "HOSTNAME#"
set cmdResponse $expect_out(buffer); # Saving the buffer output to another variable
# 'inline' and 'all' flags will cause the all matches to be returned as list
set resultList [regexp -inline -all {NAME.*?"([^"]+)?.*?DESCR.*?"([^"]+)?.*?PID.*?\s(\S+).*?,.*?VID:\s+(.*)?,.*?SN:\s(.*)?\n} $cmdResponse ]

# Quoting the values with double quotes
foreach {whole_match name descr pid vid serialno} $resultList {
        puts "NAME = \"$name\", DESCR = \"$descr\", PID = \"$pid\", VID = \"$vid\", SN = \"$serialno\""
}
```

**Output :**

```
NAME = "WS-C6506-E", DESCR = "Cisco Systems, Inc. Catalyst 6500 6-slot Chassis System", PID = "WS-C6506-E", VID = "V03", SN = "SAL1547VW8B"
NAME = "WS-C6K-VTT-E 1", DESCR = "VTT-E FRU 1", PID = "WS-C6K-VTT-E", VID = "", SN = "SMT1541B899"
NAME = "WS-C6K-VTT-E 2", DESCR = "VTT-E FRU 2", PID = "WS-C6K-VTT-E", VID = "", SN = "SMT1541B910"
NAME = "WS-C6K-VTT-E 3", DESCR = "VTT-E FRU 3", PID = "WS-C6K-VTT-E", VID = "", SN = "SMT1541B903"
NAME = "CLK-7600 1", DESCR = "OSR-7600 Clock FRU 1", PID = "CLK-7600", VID = "", SN = "SMT1544A575"
NAME = "CLK-7600 2", DESCR = "OSR-7600 Clock FRU 2", PID = "CLK-7600", VID = "", SN = "SMT1544A575"
NAME = "3", DESCR = "WS-X6724-SFP CEF720 24 port 1000mb SFP Rev. 5.1", PID = "WS-X6724-SFP", VID = "V08", SN = "SAL160214AY"
NAME = "WS-F6700-CFC Centralized Forwarding Card sub-module of 3", DESCR = "WS-F6700-CFC Centralized Forwarding Card Rev. 4.1", PID = "WS-F6700-CFC", VID = "V06", SN = "SAL160317SU"
NAME = "4", DESCR = "WS-X6324-100FX-MM 24 port 100FX Multi mode Rev. 3.6", PID = "WS-X6324-100FX-MM", VID = "", SN = "SAL091805J9"
NAME = "5", DESCR = "WS-SUP720-3B 2 ports Supervisor Engine 720 Rev. 5.6", PID = "WS-SUP720-3B", VID = "V05", SN = "SAL1226UYLK"
NAME = "msfc sub-module of 5", DESCR = "WS-SUP720 MSFC3 Daughterboard Rev. 3.1", PID = "WS-SUP720", VID = "", SN = "SAL1226UXVD"
NAME = "WS-F6K-PFC3B Policy Feature Card 3 sub-module of 5", DESCR = "WS-F6K-PFC3B Policy Feature Card 3 Rev. 2.3", PID = "WS-F6K-PFC3B", VID = "V01", SN = "SAL1225UQAQ"
NAME = "6", DESCR = "WS-X6324-100FX-MM 24 port 100FX Multi mode Rev. 3.6", PID = "WS-X6324-100FX-MM", VID = "", SN = "SAL091805HU"
NAME = "WS-C6506-E-FAN 1", DESCR = "Enhanced 6-slot Fan Tray 1", PID = "WS-C6506-E-FAN", VID = "V03", SN = "DCH1547004V"
NAME = "PS 1 WS-CAC-3000W", DESCR = "AC power supply, 3000 watt 1", PID = "WS-CAC-3000W", VID = "V02", SN = "SNI1543AX19"
NAME = "PS 2 WS-CAC-3000W", DESCR = "AC power supply, 3000 watt 2", PID = "WS-CAC-3000W", VID = "V02", SN = "SNI1543AX1F"
```

There are some entries which doesn't have `VID` info, will be displayed as empty string in the output as well.

Comment: Expect limits the amount that it buffers at once. Depending on the amount of output produced by the data source, that could be a real problem. (Searching for how to control the buffer size gives… unsatisfactory results.) Matching line by line is possibly the best approach.

Comment: I was thinking of that as a solution, but I was trying to go off of what was suggested in another thread I posted 

`http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30720779/questions-on-regex-algorithm-not-necessarily-expect-related`

another question, wouldn't .* be super greedy and get the last `SN` up till my prompt?

Also, in your `regexp` are all the matches the same element of the list? or are they separate elements? I was just wondering because I haven't seen that `foreach` before with that many arguments. curious if it's grabbing 6 elements at  time or just 1

Comment: also, you said exp_continue is misused here. when is the appropriate time to use it?

Comment: Wherever I have used `.*`, I have added `?` next to it causing the regex to behave as non-greedy. With `-inline`, all matches including subgroups are placed in a list, and due to `-all`, it will add all those matches in the same list. `foreach` will process any list based on the number of variants given.

Comment: What i meant by `exp_continue ` misusage is due to the fact that your context of requirement is not matching with what `exp_continue ` can do. One primary aspect of `exp_continue ` is handling of unknown order/sequence of output from any command line interfaced applications. If you don't know which word will come first from output, this is useful. Also, it will make cleaner code. Ironically, that aspect exhibited here causing your output to processed in different way than you expected it to be.

Comment: One other way of handling is given by Mr. Whjm where your each set of required data set is matched in one shot and `exp_continue ` causes the `Expect` to run again.

Comment: I was thinking `exp_continue` would be the correct way, since $expect_out(buffer) can't account for the length of data output. eventually you'll run into output the buffer isn't big enough to handle.

the way Mr Whjm did it is the way I originally had it, was just looking for new and better ways to do things

Comment: Agreed. I provided this solution on the basis of less amount of data which has to be held in the `expect_out(buffer)` is small in size.

Answer (score 1):

You should include all the keywords (*NAME*, *DESCR*, ...) in one single regular expression. For example:

```
$ cat foo.exp
log_user 0
spawn cat file
set info {}
expect {
    -re {NAME: "([^"]*)",\s*DESCR: "([^"]*)"\s+PID: (\S*)\s*,\s*VID:\
         (\S*)\s*,\s*SN: (\S*)} {
        set name $expect_out(1,string)
        set desc $expect_out(2,string)
        set pid  $expect_out(3,string)
        set vid  $expect_out(4,string)
        set sn   $expect_out(5,string)
        lappend info "$name | $desc | $pid | $vid | $sn"
        exp_continue
    }
}

foreach i $info {
    puts $i
}
$ cat file
NAME: "WS-C6K-VTT-E 1", DESCR: "VTT-E FRU 1"
PID: WS-C6K-VTT-E      ,                     VID:    , SN: SMT1541B899

NAME: "3", DESCR: "WS-X6724-SFP CEF720 24 port 1000mb SFP Rev. 5.1"
PID: WS-X6724-SFP      ,                     VID: V08, SN: SAL160214AY

NAME: "PS 2 WS-CAC-3000W", DESCR: "AC power supply, 3000 watt 2"
PID: WS-CAC-3000W      ,                     VID: V02, SN: SNI1543AX1F
$ expect foo.exp
WS-C6K-VTT-E 1 | VTT-E FRU 1 | WS-C6K-VTT-E |  | SMT1541B899
3 | WS-X6724-SFP CEF720 24 port 1000mb SFP Rev. 5.1 | WS-X6724-SFP | V08 | SAL160214AY
PS 2 WS-CAC-3000W | AC power supply, 3000 watt 2 | WS-CAC-3000W | V02 | SNI1543AX1F
$
```

Comment: Yes, this is the way I originally did it, but was trying a suggestion posted in another thread `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30720779/questions-on-regex-algorithm-not-necessarily-expect-related`